# Is it better to access a public field of an object multiple times or cache it in a variable?

Tags: c#

I encountered this piece of code today and it made me wonder:
Is it better to access a public field of an object multiple times in a row or does it make more sense to cache it in a local variable?

```
void AddName(Class object) {
    if (object.name != null && !list.Contains(object.name)) {
        list.Add(object.name);
    }
}
```

or

```
void AddName(Class object) {
    string name = object.name;

    if (name != null && !list.Contains(name)) {
        list.Add(name);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if in C#, accessing public fields multiple times is better or worse than caching to a local variable and allocate memory every single time the method is called.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Just try it out by **measuring**. Depending on what that field actually does, it may or may not have a huge impact on performance and memory. Asside from that public fields are considered a bad thing in most companies, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler optimization of repeated accessor calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497113/compiler-optimization-of-repeated-accessor-calls)

Comment: Accessing a field does not allocate memory. In general, do not optimize prematurely. Caching the field is semantically different from repeatedly reading it (especially if threading is involved), so there is a place for both approaches and the runtime will not turn one into the other unasked, but in general, dumping a ton of extra variables in the code that do nothing but "cache" will decrease readability and maintainability, aside from any performance differences.

Comment: Off topic: `object` is a reserved word in C#... I realize it is only example code, but still.

Comment: Incidentally, if `list` is actually a `List`, this code is a good illustration of why premature optimization is such a waste of time: `List.Contains` performs a linear search, which gets slower the more elements there are in the list. Rather than worrying about how many times `object.name` is read, the code would probably be much better off with a more appropriate container type (like `HashSet`). And even if the actual code does not look like this, the general advice to first profile to find bottlenecks and then focus on those remains effective.

Comment: In the example above there's an even easier solution that eliminates the question. If all you need is the `Name` property then you should only pass that. The argument should be a `string`, not the type that has the property. Don't pass the object in the first place if you only need one property. `void AddName(string name)`.

Comment: In such a simple case, the difference in performance is extremely neglible, if any. You might start worrying if the members you access require additional operations, e.g. `if (object.Member.GiveResult() != "InvalidResult1" && object.Member.GiveResult() != "InvalidResult2")`. However, I'd say that even in such a scenario, what matters the most is the readability and maintainability of the code. `var result = object.Member.GiveResult(); [etc.]` simply gives the reader an easier time understanding the purpose of your code.

Comment: @ScottHannen I agree with what you said, it was just to simplify the example. Of course the string should be the argument, it would make much more sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think it confirms what I suspected: no huge difference in performance. However this code is used for a mobile app so small performance gains are always welcome. 
But the bottom line is I think that using the first variant is easier on the eye and makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

[The compiler can't optimize the first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162541/is-the-c-sharp-compiler-smart-enough-to-optimize-this-code/2162893#2162893) but you won't notice a difference between the two variants. There's no measurable difference in performance and both variants consumes the same memory.

It is much more important for you (and your team) to design the code in a way that it is easy and quick to understand.