# What's better: id ?? 0 == 0 or id == null || id == 0?

Tags: c#, performance, c#-4.0

Since I have

```
public class Foo
{
  public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

What's better

```
if ((Id ?? 0) == 0) {}
```

or

```
if (Id == null || Id == 0)
```

?

Comment: which is more readable?>

Comment: since you tagged your question with "performance" - do you mean "better" in terms of performance or in terms of readability?

Comment: You should always strive to outline your question as much as possible. When you ask "what is better", it helps to describe what sort of scale you're comparing against. ie. "does X look better than Y" or "does X run faster than Y" or "will X use more memory than Y", etc. Personally I like bananas, that's much better to eat than either of your code examples.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend second one. It is more readable.

And as I have noticed, less people are familiar with `??` operator.

Comment: +1: Agree. Readability-wise, the second is superior, and I don't think performance is an issue here. Both of these will be fast enough.

Comment: I still agree that the second is more readable. But I don't buy (lack of) familiarity with `??` as an argument. If you don't know the language, go learn it. Ignorance of language syntax is no excuse.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(Id.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
```

Is also an option. In terms of performance, I doubt that there is any real difference, and in any case you would be doing micro-optimization, which is rarely beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer readability over cleverness (almost) every time, so I definitely go with: `if (Id == null || Id == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Even better would be:

```
   if(!Id.HasValue || Id == 0)
   {
   }
```

Comment: No because `Id.Value = 0`, i.e. it has value and it's 0

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged "performance", here's my general advice on such topics, which I still think is valid here:

1. Measure, measure, measure
2. Don't micro-optimize unless it's the last thing you can do, and still need to get a few cycles out of a core loop

To expand:

There could very well be things present in your code that makes such micro-optimization tips invalid or non-optimal, so your best option regarding performance is just to measure it. Make sure you measure enough iterations of a loop as measuring that small code 1 time is going to get disturbed by all the other things your machine does invalidating the whole excercise.

As for micro-optimizations, don't worry about it. Pick the one you (and whoever else is going to maintain the code) is most comfortable with, and worry about micro-optimizations if, and when, you actually need to.

Personally I often write the first, ie.

```
if (o ?? 0 == 0)
```

or, in the case of strings:

```
if ((s ?? string.Empty).Length == 0)
```

However, in terms of readability and "what looks best", this is a bikeshed problem. Go with what you want yourself and feel comfortable with, and move on to bigger issues.

**Edit**, Ok, I stopped thinking somewhere before that last code example. I combined two different things I do:

1. I never leave string properties and fields as `null` unless that is useful
2. Since 1. I can do `if (PropertyName.Length == 0)`

Of course, in that particular example I would use either of the following two:

1. `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`
2. `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))` (only in 4.0, and only if you need to)

Comment: I find `(s ?? string.Empty).Length == 0` horrible when you have `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`.

Comment: However, consider the general case: `(s ?? "").Length == x` .. I find it perfectly okay -- except for having a null at all, that is...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this code one time, it's not quite big difference what to use (but, I'd prefer second one - it's more readable). Otherwise, I'd like to give some name of condition that I verify here. E.g.

```
public class Foo
{
  public int? Id { get; set; }

  public bool IsNew
  {
    get
    {
        return (Id == null) || (Id == 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Now code says what you are verifying. And it's readable as a book

```
if (IsNew) {}
```

Comment: I like my books better when they have subjects in their sentences. Readable as a book would be: `if(this.IsNew)`. (Just joking, I don't see anything wrong with omitting `this` here)

Comment: Well, maybe that's a Haiku :)

Answer (score 1):

I reckon that in your case the first example *could* be fractionally quicker.

I did this both ways in LinqPad

```
void Main()
{
    Foo f = new Foo();
    if ((Id ?? 0) == 0) {} // if (f.Id == null || f.Id == 0) {}
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Foo
{
  public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

The IL for `if ((Id ?? 0) == 0) {}` is as follows:

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.get_Id
IL_000C:  stloc.1     
IL_000D:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_000F:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.get_HasValue
IL_0014:  brtrue.s    IL_0019
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0017:  br.s        IL_0020
IL_0019:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_001B:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.GetValueOrDefault

Foo.get_Id:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Foo.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

Foo.set_Id:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Foo.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret         

Foo..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

THE IL for `if (f.Id == null || f.Id == 0)` is below - note two calls to get_HasValue

```
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Foo..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.get_Id
IL_000C:  stloc.1     
IL_000D:  ldloca.s    01 
IL_000F:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.get_HasValue
IL_0014:  brfalse.s   IL_0031
IL_0016:  ldloc.0     
IL_0017:  callvirt    UserQuery+Foo.get_Id
IL_001C:  stloc.2     
IL_001D:  ldloca.s    02 
IL_001F:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.GetValueOrDefault
IL_0024:  brtrue.s    IL_002F
IL_0026:  ldloca.s    02 
IL_0028:  call        System.Nullable<System.Int32>.get_HasValue
IL_002D:  br.s        IL_0030
IL_002F:  ldc.i4.0    

Foo.get_Id:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldfld       UserQuery+Foo.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0006:  ret         

Foo.set_Id:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  stfld       UserQuery+Foo.<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0007:  ret         

Foo..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Maybe I should get out more!

Comment: Why is the IL generated at all relevant to the question of performance? **The IL never runs.** What is relevant to the question of performance is what code the *optimizing jitter* generates, and the jitter is probably going to inline the call to HasValue, since it is just a single read of a bool field on a struct.

Comment: Thanks for the info Eric. I guess I didn't realise that the real optimisation happens between IL and machine code rather than between C# and IL, or it may do. I have just seen your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162541/is-the-c-compiler-smart-enough-to-optimize-this-code which explains it in more detail.

Answer (score -2):

I do recommand the second one also the code should preferrably like following

```
 if (null == Id || 0 == Id)
```

Comment: Can you explain why? Even if it's for performance gains, the gain would surely be minimal and/or equivalent to the original line by the time it is optimise. What's more, it just feels backward and IMO less readable.

Comment: elkdanger, it is the normal practice from the days of VB. There for checking equal we will specify single = not two ==. Hence there are several chances the right side value will be assigned to the left valriable. Keeping that practise in my mind I just suggested it. It is NOT a must one.

Comment: Also common practice from C/C++ where the condition of an if-statement will be an integer and so mis-typing `=` instead of `==` will not result in a compile-time error.  By putting the constant value on the left there will be a compile-time error upon mis-typing because the compiler won't let you assign a variable to a constant (but the reverse is okay, hence the problem.)(