# Optimizing the property getter for a ValueType

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, compiler-construction, inline

I have an hierarchical structure of classes like this

```
public class Class1
{
    internal DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
}

public class Class2
{
    internal Class1 C1;

    public Class2(Class1 c1) { C1 = c1; }

    public DateTime Time { get { return C1.time; } }
}

public class Class3
{
    internal Class2 C2;

    public Class3(Class2 c2) { C2 = c2; }

    public DateTime Time { get { return C2.Time; } }
}

public class Class4
{
    internal Class3 C3;

    public Class4(Class3 c3) { C3 = c3; }

    public DateTime Time { get { return C3.Time; } }
}
```

I wondered when I call

```
Class4 C4 = new Class4(.....);  
Console.WriteLine(C4.Time);
```

will the ValueType data (it is DateTime in this scenario) be copied 4 times or will JIT compiler optimize the code and regenerate it as an inlined version like `C4.C3.C2.C1.time;`

C# compiler does not do any optimization. ILDASM generated code is here:

```
// get { return C3.Time; }
.method public hidebysig specialname instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime 
        get_Time() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      class CSTester.Class3 CSTester.Class4::C3
  IL_0006:  callvirt   instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime CSTester.Class3::get_Time()
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method Class4::get_Time

// get { return C2.Time; }
.method public hidebysig specialname instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime 
        get_Time() cil managed
{
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      class CSTester.Class2 CSTester.Class3::C2
  IL_0006:  callvirt   instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime CSTester.Class2::get_Time()
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method Class3::get_Time
```

EDIT: Code is compiled in release mode with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Compiled in Release with optimizations enabled ? If so, I guess the JIT will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eric Lippert says I don't know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162541/is-the-c-compiler-smart-enough-to-optimize-this-code/2162893#2162893) much more eloquently than me.

On a side note,

```
int sizeInBytes;
unsafe
{
    sizeInBytes = sizeof(DateTime);
}
```

results in a value of 8 for me but it would be *unsafe* to rely on it. The copying of 24 bytes is not worth worrying about. If it is, perhaps a lower generation of language should be used for this part of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will. Maybe it won't. Maybe it will on some versions of the CLR, on some CPU architectures, but not others.

The question you have to ask yourself is how much it really matters.

Have you got performance targets and benchmarks?

Is your code meeting them?

If it isn't, do you have reason to believe this is the bottleneck?

I find it highly unlikely that the difference between this being optimized or not would be significant in anything other than a handful of apps.

Comment: I imagine that the copying and allocation of a few `DateTime`s must be insignificant compared to the other activities performed when instantiating a reference type.

Comment: @Jodrell: I'd expect so, yes. I don't know how big `DateTime` is, but I doubt that it's more than 16 bytes...

Comment: My question is not about performance. Obviously non-optimized code is likely to copy a couple of bytes more. I even may do the inlining myself. I just wondered.

Comment: @sad_man: In what way is it not about performance when you're asking about optimization? What do you see the purpose of optimization being *other than* performance?