# Will the C# compiler remove unused local if it is assigned a property?

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-construction

This might be a silly question. I know that compiler will remove unused locals. But if I write my code like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
          ...
        }
    }

    public void SomeFunction ()
    {
       //will this line be removed if i is never used?
       int i = SomeProperty;
       ...
    }
}
```

I am wondering that if `i` will be removed by compiler because of optimization. There is logic inside the getter of `SomeProperty` that I wish to execute. If `i` will be removed, I have to change `SomeProperty` to a function.

Btw, is there a way to know which line will be optimized by compiler?

Comment: You'll be fine! Compiler it's smart enough to know

Comment: I would suggest that what the compiler does is not important. This is bad design. If calling a getter has important side effects then it should probably not be a getter. The most a getter should probably be doing is lazy initialising something and this shouldn't be important since if it doesn't happen it will just get done by the next thing to get it. I don't know what you are doing but it probably should be refactored into its own method that can be called explicitly at that point. If nothing else somebody else looking at the code might refactor it out as a pointless assignment...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2162893/284240 "**C# compiler never ever does this sort of optimization**; as noted, doing so would require that the compiler peer into the code being called and verify that the result it computes does not change over the lifetime of the callee's code. The C# compiler does not do so.

**The JIT compiler might.**"

Comment: If your code (inside SomeProperty) can be split into multiple responsibilities, one of which is to set the property the other which is to do some work that you need to get done, then it would be better to split those two out and call the "DoWhateverItIsYouNeedDone()" explicitly from SomeFunction, no?

Comment: @Chris: You should post that comment as an answer, as any correct answer is on the lines of "if you need to know then you're doing something wrong".

Comment: When I saw it in our software I thought it should be refactored. But I am just curious if this kind of code will actually work in production. Thanks guys! Your replies are all useful

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: Done. I'm never sure on whether these sorts of things should be answers since it doesn't actually answer the question but is none the less useful. Its there now for your upvoting pleasure. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest that what the compiler does is not important. This is bad design.

If calling a getter has important side effects then it should probably not be a getter. The most a getter should probably be doing is lazy initialising something and this shouldn't be important since if it doesn't happen it will just get done by the next thing to get it.

I don't know what you are doing but it probably should be refactored into its own method that can be called explicitly at that point.

The other major concern is relate to readability. Anybody seeing the line `int i = SomeProperty;` when `i` is never used again might well decide that the line is pointless and does nothing and thus remove it from the code causing whatever unexpected errors to arise. You would be better off calling a method like `LogicExtractedFromProperty()` so it is obvious you are doing something.

The compiler might (or might not, I don't know or care) do the right thing but a person may well not.

Comment: thanks guys! It is a piece of code I saw in our  software. Just curious if it will actually work :)

Comment: What if that property getter is a Lazy<T>.Value? I can't change it's design. I know the first idea would be not to use Lazy if I need it's value immediately, but that's only partial case and not always needed. But at some point I must pre-load Value and return initialized Lazy<T> object. Is it dangerous and may be changed in future versions of compiler for example?

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy: I've not used `Lazy<T>` at all so I don't know if it does anything that is particularly special but my above argument still stands I think. You should not be calling a property get just to evaluate side effects. If you think Lazy is a special case then I'd advise asking a question about its behaviour specifically (with reference to this question perhaps and why you think the answer doesn't apply).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I decided to add guard clause after call to Value property: if (!lazy.IsValueCreated){ //Write warning message }. It will use the values modified by getter and ensure it is not removed by compiler. Unfortunately I can't avoid relying on behavior of that getter (withing reasonable time).

Comment: What if I'm using external lib (say System.Windows.Forms) so have no control over your "dab design" stuff. And want to initiate some actions (say pre-create ImageList.Handle which is a property) - how can then I ensure that call would not be removed by JIT optimization as unused?

Comment: So does it mean that if it is a Get method, JIT(or the compiler?) would respect the side effect and actually not to optimize the line?

Comment: @joe: As my answer says I have no idea and I don't much care since it would be an absolutely terrible idea to have code like this in the first place... Why do you feel it important to know? Are you trying to do something like the above?

Comment: @Chris ummm... In my case I was actually writing a benchmark to test different methods' performance. I was not sure if the JIT would wipe the actual methods out.  I need to make sure the methods actually run. The methods are always there in IL as expected. And I have confirmed JIT won't wipe out methods as long as it has some side effects(but it will in some cases), which means in my case I don't need to worry about this. see my [shraplab example](https://sharplab.io/#gist:ebb3abe526bcdd77e54dd8b0eac20e79) in .net core 3

Comment: @joe: If they are methods then it defintiely won't get rid of them. That's not what this question is about though, its about *properties* with side effects. And probably it won't get rid of them but since you shouldn't have properties that only have side effects it doesn't matter what the compiler does with them. For what its worth in your example you don't need to assign to myTemp. Calling a method without assigning its result is perfectly acceptable.