# Will C# compiler and optimization break this code?

Tags: c#, optimization, compilation, resharper

Given the following C# code inside a function:

```
....
var documentCollection =
    client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery("dbs/" + database.Id)
        .Where(c => c.Id == DocumentCollectionName)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .FirstOrDefault();

if (documentCollection == null)
{
    documentCollection =
        await
        client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
            "dbs/" + database.Id,
            new DocumentCollection { Id = DocumentCollectionName });
}

return client;
```

Note: I'm *not* returning the `documentCollection`, I just need it to be initialized, if not already ( the `CreateDocumentCollectionAsync` call ). So - after the `if` block , `documentCollection` becomes an unused variable.

Now - ReSharper proposes to optimize this to:

```
var documentCollection =
    client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery("dbs/" + database.Id)
        .Where(c => c.Id == DocumentCollectionName)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .FirstOrDefault()
    ?? await
        client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
            "dbs/" + database.Id,
            new DocumentCollection { Id = DocumentCollectionName });
```

And indicates now that `documentCollection` is an unused variable.

**My question:** will C# code optimization or a 'release' build completely remove this line of code and result in the `CreateDocumentCollectionAsync` to never fire?

The C# optimization course taught me that 'release' builds garbage collect variables as soon as they're not needed 'down the line' in the function, whereas debug builds don't do that (for debugging purposes).

I'm now wondering whether it's so eager even that it optimizes away an unused variable assignment (which triggers an operation in the background).

Comment: I believe it can optimize away the unused variable assignment, but not the asynchronous operation that it triggers. If `CreateDocumentCollectionAsync` causes any side-effects, these should always be visible to your program.

Comment: missed something obvious. inside if statement just write `await client.....`(dont assign it.)

Comment: How does the unused variable assignment "trigger an operation in the background"?

Comment: @JonHanna because `client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync()` has side-effects.

Comment: So? If you called the method and didn't assign the results to a variable, how would that affect its side-effects?

Comment: @JonHanna It wouldn't. But the question is whether the method call is optimized away by the C# compiler.

Comment: The last sentence asks "I'm now wondering whether it's so eager even that it optimizes away an unused variable assignment", which it probably does do, but which wouldn't matter.

Comment: Your statement that a release-mode program **will as soon as possible** aggressively collect objects whose only remaining reference is in a never-used-again variable is incorrect; the GC is not *required* to do so. Rather, the GC is *permitted* to do so. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't, depending on things like whether the variable was enregistered.

Comment: The relevant question here is not whether the call will be optimized away just because its return value is not used. The jitter could only do that if the call was *dead*, not if its result was unused. The more interesting question is whether the object in question has a finalizer. If it does then the GC is free to finalize it *before* the variable goes out of scope, if the variable is optimized away. In fact, the finalizer is permitted to run on an object *concurrent with its constructor* if the GC determines that the object is never referenced. This is a very weird situation to be in.

Comment: @EricLippert - thank you for your contribution. Comments like these make me *very* humble in terms of my own skills and knowledge. Because I don't know half the things you mentioned. What's a 'dead' call for instance? Are there any resources you can point me towards to learn more about this - except maybe your blog or work at MS for 16 years ? :)

Comment: @JochenvanWylick: By a "dead" call I mean a call in code that can be determined to be never called.  `if(false) M();` is the most obvious example of a dead call; the jitter is permitted to simply *never generate the code* for the call. Both the C# compiler and the jitter can eliminate dead code; C# will eliminate the `if(false)` scenario, but will not eliminate a scenario like `int x = whatever; if (x * 0 != 0) M();` Whether the jitter actually does so, I do not know.

Comment: What does it matter? You're using Linq, which is the exact opposite of performance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, neither the compiler, nor JIT, will optimize your method call away.

There is a [list of what the JIT compiler does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx). It does optimize away `if (false) { ... }` blocks for example, or unused variable assignments. It does not just optimize away your method calls. If that was true, every call to a `void` method should be gone too.

Comment: That list (assuming I found the right one) is neither definite, nor complete and certainly subject to change, since optimisations are nothing but implementation details. The rules under which the compiler has to operate can be simplified (ignoring concurrency) as "any optimisation is valid as long as it does not change the observable program behavior". Hence if the compiler could prove that the calls have no observable effect then yes it could optimize them away.

Answer (score 16):

**No.**

Any optimiser may only remove code that has no observable behaviour.

Otherwise it's not an optimiser.

Comment: Right. This is the true answer. The other answers mostly point to implementation details. This answer is better because it argues by contract.

Comment: @usr: Feel free to write your own if you want to say the same thing in different words :P

Comment: Seemed like a waste.

Comment: Good, +1. Just one question *(not related to the question)*. How you have learned English? What reference?

Comment: I wonder, how do you know I know Farsi? (And go it, Seems English is your native language. Good for you)

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I don't imagine you'd be a terribly effective member of Iranian society if you did not know how to speak Farsi.

Answer (score 15):

Disclaimer:
This is implementation detail which is subject to change, take it with a grain of salt.

---

ECMA-335 of the CLI specification, section I.12.6.4 (Optimizations) states the following:

> Conforming implementations of the CLI are free to execute programs
> using any technology that guarantees, within a single thread of
> execution, that side-effects and exceptions generated by a thread are
> visible in the order specified by the CIL. For this purpose only
> volatile operations (including volatile reads) constitute visible
> side-effects. (Note that while only volatile operations constitute
> visible side-effects, volatile operations also affect the visibility
> of non-volatile references.) Volatile operations are specified in
> §I.12.6.7. There are no ordering guarantees relative to exceptions
> injected into a thread by another thread (such exceptions are
> sometimes called “asynchronous exceptions” (e.g.,
> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException).
>
> [Rationale: An optimizing
> compiler is free to **reorder side-effects and synchronous exceptions to
> the extent that this reordering does not change any observable program
> behavior.** end rationale]
>
> [Note: An
> implementation of the CLI is permitted to use an optimizing compiler,
> for example, to convert CIL to native machine code provided the
> compiler maintains (within each single thread of execution) **the same
> order of side-effects and synchronous exceptions.** This is a stronger
> condition than ISO C++ (which permits reordering between a pair of
> sequence points) or ISO Scheme (which permits reordering of arguments
> to functions). end note]

This means that any implementation conforming to the CLI is free to make such optimizations if **it can guarantee that the order of side-effects aren't harmed.** This means that if a method has no side-effect and the JIT or language compiler statically analyze that for a *given fact*, it *may* optimize it away as there will be no re-ordering of said side-effects with or without that method.

That being said, currently, the C# compiler *will* optimize out the unused variable, but not the method call. There is no static analysis of the entire method call being done by the compiler, so it can't "prove" the method has no side-effect in your code. More-so, the JIT optimizations aren't as aggressive, it may only inline the method call, but not optimize it away.

Being open-source, you can see the x86 JIT compilation phases and [get a look at some optimizations being done](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/jit/compphases.h) (via `compphases.h`):

```
// Names of x86 JIT phases, in order.  Assumes that the caller defines CompPhaseNameMacro
// in a useful way before including this file, e.g., to define the phase enumeration and the
// corresponding array of string names of those phases.  This include file undefines CompPhaseNameMacro
// after the last use.
// The arguments are:
//   CompPhaseNameMacro(enumName, stringName, hasChildren, parent)
//     "enumName" is an Enumeration-style all-caps name.
//     "stringName" is a self-explanatory.
//     "hasChildren" is true if this phase is broken out into subphases.
//         (We should never do EndPhase on a phase that has children, only on 'leaf phases.')
//     "parent" is -1 for leaf phases, otherwise it is the "enumName" of the parent phase.

CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_PRE_IMPORT,             "Pre-import",                     "PRE-IMP",  false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_IMPORTATION,            "Importation",                    "IMPORT",   false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_POST_IMPORT,            "Post-import",                    "POST-IMP", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_MORPH,                  "Morph",                          "MORPH",    false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_GS_COOKIE,              "GS Cookie",                      "GS-COOK",  false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_COMPUTE_PREDS,          "Compute preds",                  "PREDS",    false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_MARK_GC_POLL_BLOCKS,    "Mark GC poll blocks",            "GC-POLL",  false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_COMPUTE_EDGE_WEIGHTS,   "Compute edge weights (1)",       "EDG-WGT",  false, -1)
#if FEATURE_EH_FUNCLETS
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_CREATE_FUNCLETS,        "Create EH funclets",             "EH-FUNC",  false, -1)
#endif // FEATURE_EH_FUNCLETS
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_OPTIMIZE_LAYOUT,        "Optimize layout",                "LAYOUT",   false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_OPTIMIZE_LOOPS,         "Optimize loops",                 "LOOP-OPT", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_CLONE_LOOPS,            "Clone loops",                    "LP-CLONE", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_UNROLL_LOOPS,           "Unroll loops",                   "UNROLL",   false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_HOIST_LOOP_CODE,        "Hoist loop code",                "LP-HOIST", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_MARK_LOCAL_VARS,        "Mark local vars",                "MARK-LCL", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_OPTIMIZE_BOOLS,         "Optimize bools",                 "OPT-BOOL", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_FIND_OPER_ORDER,        "Find oper order",                "OPER-ORD", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_SET_BLOCK_ORDER,        "Set block order",                "BLK-ORD",  false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA,              "Build SSA representation",       "SSA",      true,  -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA_TOPOSORT,     "SSA: topological sort",          "SSA-SORT", false, PHASE_BUILD_SSA)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA_DOMS,         "SSA: Doms1",                     "SSA-DOMS", false, PHASE_BUILD_SSA)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA_LIVENESS,     "SSA: liveness",                  "SSA-LIVE", false, PHASE_BUILD_SSA)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA_IDF,          "SSA: IDF",                       "SSA-IDF",  false, PHASE_BUILD_SSA)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA_INSERT_PHIS,  "SSA: insert phis",               "SSA-PHI",  false, PHASE_BUILD_SSA)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_BUILD_SSA_RENAME,       "SSA: rename",                    "SSA-REN",  false, PHASE_BUILD_SSA)

CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_EARLY_PROP,             "Early Value Propagation",        "ERL-PROP", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_VALUE_NUMBER,           "Do value numbering",             "VAL-NUM",  false, -1)

CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_OPTIMIZE_INDEX_CHECKS,  "Optimize index checks",          "OPT-CHK",  false, -1)

#if FEATURE_VALNUM_CSE
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_OPTIMIZE_VALNUM_CSES,   "Optimize Valnum CSEs",           "OPT-CSE",  false, -1)
#endif  

CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_VN_COPY_PROP,           "VN based copy prop",             "CP-PROP",  false, -1)
#if ASSERTION_PROP
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_ASSERTION_PROP_MAIN,    "Assertion prop",                 "AST-PROP", false, -1)
#endif
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_UPDATE_FLOW_GRAPH,      "Update flow graph",              "UPD-FG",   false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_COMPUTE_EDGE_WEIGHTS2,  "Compute edge weights (2)",       "EDG-WGT2", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_DETERMINE_FIRST_COLD_BLOCK, "Determine first cold block", "COLD-BLK", false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_RATIONALIZE,            "Rationalize IR",                 "RAT",      false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_SIMPLE_LOWERING,        "Do 'simple' lowering",           "SMP-LWR",  false, -1)

CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS,         "Local var liveness",             "LIVENESS", true, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS_INIT,    "Local var liveness init",        "LIV-INIT", false, PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS_PERBLOCK,"Per block local var liveness",   "LIV-BLK",  false, PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS_INTERBLOCK,  "Global local var liveness",  "LIV-GLBL", false, PHASE_LCLVARLIVENESS)

CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LVA_ADJUST_REF_COUNTS,  "LVA adjust ref counts",          "REF-CNT",  false, -1)

#ifdef LEGACY_BACKEND
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_RA_ASSIGN_VARS,         "RA assign vars",                 "REGALLOC", false, -1)
#endif // LEGACY_BACKEND
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LOWERING_DECOMP,        "Lowering decomposition",         "LWR-DEC",  false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LOWERING,               "Lowering nodeinfo",              "LWR-INFO", false, -1)
#ifndef LEGACY_BACKEND
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN,            "Linear scan register alloc",     "LSRA",     true, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN_BUILD,      "LSRA build intervals",           "LSRA-BLD", false, PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN_ALLOC,      "LSRA allocate",                  "LSRA-ALL", false, PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN_RESOLVE,    "LSRA resolve",                   "LSRA-RES", false, PHASE_LINEAR_SCAN)
#endif // !LEGACY_BACKEND
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_GENERATE_CODE,          "Generate code",                  "CODEGEN",  false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_EMIT_CODE,              "Emit code",                      "EMIT",     false, -1)
CompPhaseNameMacro(PHASE_EMIT_GCEH,              "Emit GC+EH tables",              "EMT-GCEH", false, -1)
```

Some optimizations are:

- Dead code elimination
- Linear Scan Register Allocation
- Loop unrolling
- Range check elimiation

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25801/JIT-Optimizations) goes on to describe some of the optimizations done by the JIT, and there is a great answer by @EricLippert talking in general about optimizations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162893/1870803)

Comment: Might it optimize away a call to a `[Pure]` method?

Comment: @IllidanS4 If the method is marked as `[Pure]` and the return value is discarded, this *could* fall under dead-code elimination. More on that [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/285332/)