# Repeated access to properties and speed in C#

Tags: c#, c++, performance, properties

I usually work with C++ but I have more and more to write and maintain C# code.

Now I see very often in C# code like this:

```
Application.Current.Properties.Remove("a");
Application.Current.Properties.Remove("b");
Application.Current.Properties.Remove("c");
```

For me this looks like time wasting. Because I really don't know what is going on inside accessing such a property. Yes. I can look into the source code, but I usually don't like to look into the code of every function I use.

I normally wouldn't write code like this in C++. I would try to get a reference to the object and use it. In C# code I see more sense in writing:

```
var props = Application.Current.Properties;
props.Remove("a");
props.Remove("b");
props.Remove("c");
```

It matters how intelligent is the compiler. Using my method needs nearly no optimization. The `IDictionary` object is acquired once and used.

So my question is:

How good is the C# compiler? Is it intelligent enough to reduce the code that is needed for repeatedly access to a nested property, or is it worth to use references to such properties?

To make it not to broad: The properties shouldn't be constructed in a way that they always read the data from anywhere... It is clear to me that using a complicated getter in `Application.Current.Properties` would be expensive.

**EDIT** To avoid that the question is closed.
Assume that we have a simple getter that just returns a stored variable/object. Even than I see a performance issue.
So in more detail: Using `Application.Current.Properties`  is an indirection of 2 objects.
Is the compiler capable to optimize this?

Comment: It really depends on what `.Current` and `.Properties` does as to whether it's significantly more efficient. You could just write the code and view the IL output. But it seems a little like premature optimisation here, and even if it isn't, it's a bit opinion based as to which style is preferred.

Comment: Property getter is just a function, it might have side effects, so in general those two pieces of code are not equivalent. So I don't think it's even possible for C# compiler to "optimize" code in this way.

Comment: While there is surely no reason to write the same code again and again you can (and almost) *should* extract a variable for the common parts instead of calling the getters again. However as Evk allready mentioned you have to ensure that no side-effects occur within the getters. So I´m voting to close this question as either too broad or opinion-based as there is no generel solution to this.

Comment: I found this answer where Eric Lippert (former member of C# compiler team) talks about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162893/5311735

Comment: @Evk: The answer from Eric Lippert is interesting but for the shown case, the answer would be obvious for me. Not using the object 'should' be faster... I try to do some checks on my own.

Comment: Changed my question to make it less broad.

Comment: Eric says that C# compiler never optimizes this, but JIT (the one which compiles IL into native assembly at runtime) compiler is allowed to do that, though whether it actually does that - he has no idea. At least JIT compiler can certainly inline simple property accessors. So in short - you should not rely on compiler here and do what you think is better (that is - use your second code block).

Comment: @Evk: I would accept this as an answer!